# Emacs Org Mode Structural Markup Elements Not Exporting in OpenBSD

Tags: emacs, export, openbsd

I am running Emacs 24.5.1 on OpenBSD 6.0 and running into an issue with exporting (in org-mode) to any format. I have installed the texlive-full package available in OpenBSD.

Exporting works fine unless I use structural markup elements (i.e. #+TITLE: Test Title, or #+AUTHOR: Author Name). When I include these elements Emacs complains and refuses:

```
Wrong type arguement: listp, #("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#0)))
```

When I toggle-debug-on-error and do the same:

Debugger entered--Lisp error:

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#1))))
  org-element-set-contents(#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#0))))
  apply(org-element-set-contents #("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#0))) nil)
  #[(s) \306\307\31#\311\312    \211:\204\313\202\"
                                                       @9\203!
 AA\202\"
         )\"\210\314\315\n     \211:\2043\313\202@
                                                   @9\203?
                                                          AA\202@
    )#\210 \316\211\n
                       ;\203V\317\320\f
                                       #\202\\\321
                                                  A@\f\"*\211;\203n\322
$\202z       \313\f
      A\323
#\240\210  A@\f
         +\210\nA       A@\240\210\n    @\240*\207" [s new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) \305      211;\203\306\f\307
                                           \n$\202 \fA\310\fA@
 \n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 6](#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#0))))
  #[(--data) \211:\204  ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337
    \203\307
            \310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\202\337\>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\31;\204\312\n\236A\313\211203\311@\f        ;\203\266\317\320       #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211203\201@\211 @        ;\203\317\320   #\202
                                                 \307       A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\2112042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241     @9\203\240      AA\202\241      )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\\211:\204\320\313\202\335     @9\203\334      AA\202\335      )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6](#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent (#0))))
  mapc(#[(--data) \211:\204     ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337
            \203\307
                    \310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\2>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\31;\204\312\n\236A\313\211203\311@\f        ;\203\266\317\320       #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211203\201@\211 @        ;\203\317\320   #\202
                                                 \307       A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\2112042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241     @9\203\240      AA\202\241      )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\\211:\204\320\313\202\335     @9\203\334      AA\202\335      )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6] (#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent #0))))
  #[(--data) \211:\204  ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337
    \203\307
            \310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\202\337\>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\31;\204\312\n\236A\313\211203\311@\f        ;\203\266\317\320       #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211203\201@\211 @        ;\203\317\320   #\202
                                                 \307       A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\2112042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241     @9\203\240      AA\202\241      )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\\211:\204\320\313\202\335     @9\203\334      AA\202\335      )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6]((#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent #0))))
  byte-code(    !\210\n\237\207" [--walk-tree data --acc] 2)
  org-element-map((#("Test Title" 0 10 (:parent #0))) plain-text #[(s) \306\307\31#\311\312     \211:\204\313\202\"
                                                          @9\203!
    AA\202\"
            )\"\210\314\315\n     \211:\2043\313\202@
                                                      @9\203?
AA\202@
       )#\210 \316\211\n
                          ;\203V\317\320\f
                                          #\202\\\321
                                                     A@\f\"*\211;\203n\322
$\202z          \313\f
      A\323
#\240\210  A@\f
         +\210\nA       A@\240\210\n    @\240*\207" [s new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) \305      211;\203\306\f\307
                                           \n$\202 \fA\310\fA@
 \n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 6])
  org-export--get-inbuffer-options([cl-struct-org-export-backend latex nil ((bold . org-latex-bold) (center-block . org-latex-center-block) (clock . org-latex-clock) (code . org-latex-code) (drawer . org-latex-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-latex-dynamic-block) (entity . org-latex-entity) (example-block . org-latex-example-block) (export-block . org-latex-export-block) (export-snippet . org-latex-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-latex-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-latex-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-latex-footnote-reference) (headline . org-latex-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-latex-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-latex-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-latex-inlinetask) (italic . org-latex-italic) (item . org-latex-item) (keyword . org-latex-keyword) (latex-environment . org-latex-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-latex-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-latex-line-break) (link . org-latex-link) (node-property . org-latex-node-property) (paragraph . org-latex-paragraph) (plain-list . org-latex-plain-list) (plain-text . org-latex-plain-text) (planning . org-latex-planning) (property-drawer . org-latex-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-latex-quote-block) (radio-target . org-latex-radio-target) (section . org-latex-section) (special-block . org-latex-special-block) (src-block . org-latex-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-latex-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-latex-strike-through) (subscript . org-latex-subscript) (superscript . org-latex-superscript) (table . org-latex-table) (table-cell . org-latex-table-cell) (table-row . org-latex-table-row) (target . org-latex-target) (template . org-latex-template) (timestamp . org-latex-timestamp) (underline . org-latex-underline) (verbatim . org-latex-verbatim) (verse-block . org-latex-verse-block) (latex-math-block . org-latex-math-block) (latex-matrices . org-latex-matrices)) ((:latex-class "LATEX_CLASS" nil org-latex-default-class t) (:latex-class-options "LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS" nil nil t) (:latex-header "LATEX_HEADER" nil nil newline) (:latex-header-extra "LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA" nil nil newline) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil parse) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil parse) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:latex-active-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-active-timestamp-format) (:latex-caption-above nil nil org-latex-caption-above) (:latex-classes nil nil org-latex-classes) (:latex-default-figure-position nil nil org-latex-default-figure-position) (:latex-default-table-environment nil nil org-latex-default-table-environment) (:latex-default-table-mode nil nil org-latex-default-table-mode) (:latex-diary-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-diary-timestamp-format) (:latex-footnote-separator nil nil org-latex-footnote-separator) (:latex-format-drawer-function nil nil org-latex-format-drawer-function) (:latex-format-headline-function nil nil org-latex-format-headline-function) (:latex-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-latex-format-inlinetask-function) (:latex-hyperref-template nil nil org-latex-hyperref-template t) (:latex-image-default-height nil nil org-latex-image-default-height) (:latex-image-default-option nil nil org-latex-image-default-option) (:latex-image-default-width nil nil org-latex-image-default-width) (:latex-inactive-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-inactive-timestamp-format) (:latex-inline-image-rules nil nil org-latex-inline-image-rules) (:latex-link-with-unknown-path-format nil nil org-latex-link-with-unknown-path-format) (:latex-listings nil nil org-latex-listings) (:latex-listings-langs nil nil org-latex-listings-langs) (:latex-listings-options nil nil org-latex-listings-options) (:latex-minted-langs nil nil org-latex-minted-langs) (:latex-minted-options nil nil org-latex-minted-options) (:latex-prefer-user-labels nil nil org-latex-prefer-user-labels) (:latex-subtitle-format nil nil org-latex-subtitle-format) (:latex-subtitle-separate nil nil org-latex-subtitle-separate) (:latex-table-scientific-notation nil nil org-latex-table-scientific-notation) (:latex-tables-booktabs nil nil org-latex-tables-booktabs) (:latex-tables-centered nil nil org-latex-tables-centered) (:latex-text-markup-alist nil nil org-latex-text-markup-alist) (:latex-title-command nil nil org-latex-title-command) (:latex-toc-command nil nil org-latex-toc-command) (:date "DATE" nil "\\today" parse)) ((:filter-options . org-latex-math-block-options-filter) (:filter-parse-tree org-latex-math-block-tree-filter org-latex-matrices-tree-filter)) ("LATEX" "TEX") (108 "Export to LaTeX" ((76 "As LaTeX buffer" org-latex-export-as-latex) (108 "As LaTeX file" org-latex-export-to-latex) (112 "As PDF file" org-latex-export-to-pdf) (111 "As PDF file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-latex-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil s v b)))))))])
  org-export-get-environment([cl-struct-org-export-backend latex nil ((bold . org-latex-bold) (center-block . org-latex-center-block) (clock . org-latex-clock) (code . org-latex-code) (drawer . org-latex-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-latex-dynamic-block) (entity . org-latex-entity) (example-block . org-latex-example-block) (export-block . org-latex-export-block) (export-snippet . org-latex-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-latex-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-latex-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-latex-footnote-reference) (headline . org-latex-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-latex-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-latex-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-latex-inlinetask) (italic . org-latex-italic) (item . org-latex-item) (keyword . org-latex-keyword) (latex-environment . org-latex-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-latex-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-latex-line-break) (link . org-latex-link) (node-property . org-latex-node-property) (paragraph . org-latex-paragraph) (plain-list . org-latex-plain-list) (plain-text . org-latex-plain-text) (planning . org-latex-planning) (property-drawer . org-latex-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-latex-quote-block) (radio-target . org-latex-radio-target) (section . org-latex-section) (special-block . org-latex-special-block) (src-block . org-latex-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-latex-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-latex-strike-through) (subscript . org-latex-subscript) (superscript . org-latex-superscript) (table . org-latex-table) (table-cell . org-latex-table-cell) (table-row . org-latex-table-row) (target . org-latex-target) (template . org-latex-template) (timestamp . org-latex-timestamp) (underline . org-latex-underline) (verbatim . org-latex-verbatim) (verse-block . org-latex-verse-block) (latex-math-block . org-latex-math-block) (latex-matrices . org-latex-matrices)) ((:latex-class "LATEX_CLASS" nil org-latex-default-class t) (:latex-class-options "LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS" nil nil t) (:latex-header "LATEX_HEADER" nil nil newline) (:latex-header-extra "LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA" nil nil newline) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil parse) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil parse) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:latex-active-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-active-timestamp-format) (:latex-caption-above nil nil org-latex-caption-above) (:latex-classes nil nil org-latex-classes) (:latex-default-figure-position nil nil org-latex-default-figure-position) (:latex-default-table-environment nil nil org-latex-default-table-environment) (:latex-default-table-mode nil nil org-latex-default-table-mode) (:latex-diary-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-diary-timestamp-format) (:latex-footnote-separator nil nil org-latex-footnote-separator) (:latex-format-drawer-function nil nil org-latex-format-drawer-function) (:latex-format-headline-function nil nil org-latex-format-headline-function) (:latex-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-latex-format-inlinetask-function) (:latex-hyperref-template nil nil org-latex-hyperref-template t) (:latex-image-default-height nil nil org-latex-image-default-height) (:latex-image-default-option nil nil org-latex-image-default-option) (:latex-image-default-width nil nil org-latex-image-default-width) (:latex-inactive-timestamp-format nil nil org-latex-inactive-timestamp-format) (:latex-inline-image-rules nil nil org-latex-inline-image-rules) (:latex-link-with-unknown-path-format nil nil org-latex-link-with-unknown-path-format) (:latex-listings nil nil org-latex-listings) (:latex-listings-langs nil nil org-latex-listings-langs) (:latex-listings-options nil nil org-latex-listings-options) (:latex-minted-langs nil nil org-latex-minted-langs) (:latex-minted-options nil nil org-latex-minted-options) (:latex-prefer-user-labels nil nil org-latex-prefer-user-labels) (:latex-subtitle-format nil nil org-latex-subtitle-format) (:latex-subtitle-separate nil nil org-latex-subtitle-separate) (:latex-table-scientific-notation nil nil org-latex-table-scientific-notation) (:latex-tables-booktabs nil nil org-latex-tables-booktabs) (:latex-tables-centered nil nil org-latex-tables-centered) (:latex-text-markup-alist nil nil org-latex-text-markup-alist) (:latex-title-command nil nil org-latex-title-command) (:latex-toc-command nil nil org-latex-toc-command) (:date "DATE" nil "\\today" parse)) ((:filter-options . org-latex-math-block-options-filter) (:filter-parse-tree org-latex-math-block-tree-filter org-latex-matrices-tree-filter)) ("LATEX" "TEX") (108 "Export to LaTeX" ((76 "As LaTeX buffer" org-latex-export-as-latex) (108 "As LaTeX file" org-latex-export-to-latex) (112 "As PDF file" org-latex-export-to-pdf) (111 "As PDF file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-latex-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil s v b)))))))] nil (:output-file "./test.tex"))
  org-export-as(latex nil nil nil (:output-file "./test.tex"))
  org-export-to-file(latex "./test.tex" nil nil nil nil nil #[(file) "\30!\207" [file org-latex-compile] 2])
  org-latex-export-to-pdf(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it figures after having several days of trouble with this I would find a solution a few minutes after posting my question here.

I am not sure WHY the below steps fixed my problem, but they did.

First, I deleted all installed packages from emacs:

```
rm -rf .emacs.d/elpa/*
```

Then I deleted the emacs package, the texlive-full packages, and dependencies.

```
pkg_delete emacs texlive_texmf-full
pkg_delete -a
```

After that I re-installed texlive-full and emacs in that order. (not sure it matters, but that is what I did).

Now I am exporting!